# Sum data in column with criteria in row

Tags: sumifs

I wish to make a formula to sum up the value with 2 criteria, example show as below:-

```
    A    B       C       D        E
1       1-Apr   2-Apr   3-Apr   4-Apr
2   aa    1      4       7       10
3   bb    2      5       8       11
4   cc    3      6       9       12
5           
6  Criteria 1       bb      
7  Range start      2-Apr-16        
8  Range End        4-Apr-16        
9  Total sum        #VALUE!
```

tried formula
1   `SUMIF(A2:A4,C6,INDEX(B2:E4,0,MATCH(C7,B1:E1,0)))`
    * Only return 1 cell value

2   `SUMIF(A2:A4,C6,INDEX(B2:E4,0,MATCH(">="&C7,B1:E1,0)))`
    * Showed N/A error

3   `SUMIFS(B2:E4,A2:A4,C6,B1:E1,">="&C7,B1:E1,"<="&C8)`
    * Showed #Value error

Hereby I attached a link of picture for better understanding : [image: Table]

Can anyone help me on the formula?

Comment: welcome to SO. Please post your example table directly to SO (rather than as a linked image). Also, please show us what code you've tried and any error messages you are getting.

Comment: Hi Richard, I copy and paste it directly on the comment box, it seem dis-oriental, anyhow, I have attached another picture that should able to explain my question more clearly. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution with step evaluation:

```
=SUMIF(B1:F1,">="&C7,INDEX(B2:F4,MATCH(C6,A2:A4,0),0)) - 
 SUMIF(B1:F1,">"&C8,INDEX(B2:F4,MATCH(C6,A2:A4,0),0))
```

Comment: If you solved your own problem, please be sure to make your question as solved.